# create a pdf bigger than 5080x5080?

Tags: pdf, python-3.5, reportlab

is it possible to create a pdf that is bigger than `5080x5080`? 
Reportlab seems to be limited to only `5080x5080`.

Here is an example:

```
from reportlab.lib.units import mm
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

pdf = canvas.Canvas("eg.pdf", pagesize = (10000 * mm, 10000 * mm))
pdf.showPage()
pdf.save()
```

This code only creates a `5080x5080` pdf ... 
for the project I'm currently working on I'd need bigger pdf files up to 30m (30000 * mm)

So the question is there a way around it?

I'm using Python 3.5.2 and Windows 10.

Comment: You want to create a PDF that's over 5 meters on a side? I'm not surprised it's having trouble with that. It's not uncommon for software to impose some reasonable limits. Can you produce a larger PDF using Adobe's tools?

Comment: There used to be a limit of 14400 by 14400 user units; see [Help, I only see blank pages in my PDF](https://itextpdf.com/sandbox/blankpage14400). This was an implementation limit in Adobe Reader; other viewers will show larger documents. The limit was dropped when PDF became an ISO standard (ISO-32000-2 is the most recent version). Some viewers might still have the implementation limit, but there's nothing that prevents you to create such a PDF.

Comment: By default one user unit equals 1 pt, so the old limit of 14400 x 14400 user units corresponded with 200 x 200 inch. However, there is also the concept of the user unit (see [How to get the UserUnit from a PDF file?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/inspect-pdf/itext7-how-get-userunit-pdf-file)). The maximum value of the user unit is 75000. This means that you can create a PDF with a size of 15M x 15M inch, or 381 square km (yes, that's not a typo: I am talking about KILOmeters).

Comment: In case you think that this doesn't make sense, just consider that PDFs are no longer meant to be printed in the digital age. It can make sense to create such PDFs in the context of engineering (like blueprints for large building projects).

Comment: The size of the page shouldn't have any impact on the way documents are processed. Limitations are caused by the fact that we store that size as an `int`, `long`, `double` or a `float` in our programming languages. Opening a file with a page that measures 381 square km can be less a problem than opening a file with a page of size Letter that has a million of objects in it. Now *that* would be a problem. I hope that's a comprehensive answer to your remark, @MarkRansom

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I wasn't making a statement about what was *possible*, I was merely pointing out that for practical reasons there are often limits imposed. I don't know enough about the history of PDF to know what those limits were, so thank you for that information. At this point the uses of PDF have expanded far beyond what its inventors could have imagined.

Comment: thank you for your comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after a "few" hours of research i found these link

- [large-dimension-pdf-files-are-fine-adobe-is-the-problem](https://graphics-unleashed.com/2011/06/large-dimension-pdf-files-are-fine-adobe-is-the-problem/)
- [When-200-inch-page-limit-broken](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/When-200-inch-page-limit-broken-q36927.aspx)

so the problem was the reader i used 
once i switched to [foxit](https://www.foxitsoftware.com/pdf-reader/) i could see the generated file as it was intended 
so the code above is correct

still i would like to thank you guys for the quick comments especially [Bruno Lowagie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1622493/bruno-lowagie)

Comment: *"so the problem was the reader i used"* - that's wrong. The PDF specification clearly indicates that the size of a page in default user units supported by a Reader may be limited to a given size, and you crossed that limit. If one wants to make larger PDFs, one should change the size of a user unit. This is also described in the standard, and if you go that way, Adobe Reader happily displays larger PDF pages. So the problem is the PDF generator that creates large PDF page sizes in a way PDF viewers are not required to support.

Comment: @mkl evidently the PDF specification is changing over time, based on the comments by Bruno Lowagie. The most robust solution is to change the unit size as you suggest, but do you know how to do that in `reportlab`? If so you should leave an answer, I'd give it an upvote myself. I took a quick glance at the documentation and didn't find anything.